# C++ split string with \0 into list

Tags: c++, list, split, delimiter

I want to List the logical drives with:

```
const size_t BUFSIZE = 100;
char buffer[ BUFSIZE ];
memset(buffer,0,BUFSIZE);

//get available drives
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDriveStringsA(BUFSIZE,static_cast<LPSTR>(buffer));
```

The buffer then contains: `'C',':','\','0'`
[image: The buffer after GetLogicalDriveStringA()]

Now I want to have a List filled with `"C:\"`,`"D:\"` and so on. Therefore I tried something like this:

```
std::string tmp(buffer,BUFSIZE);//to split this string then
QStringList drivesList = QString::fromStdString(tmp).split("\0");
```

But it didn't worked. Is it even possible to split with the delimiter `\0`? Or is there a way to split by length?

Comment: Because `\0` ends the string, I guess you can't use it as a delimiter

Comment: The "list" returned from [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) is double-nullchar-terminated (inconveniently omitted from your memory view snapshot). so you can enumerate the string via lengths obtained for each segment using looped `strlen` and pointer arithmetic, until you encounter a zero-length segment. When that happens, you're done.

Comment: Yeah that was my first approach with `while(i<drives){ i += strlen( &buffer[i] ) + 1; }` it worked, but I was hopeing to find a nicer solution where I can iterate through a list.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `String::fromStdString(tmp)` is that it will create a string only from the first zero-terminated "entry" in your buffer, because that's how *standard strings* works. It is certainly possible, but you have to do it yourself manually instead.

You can do it by finding the first zero, extract the substring, then in a loop until you find two consecutive zeroes, do just the same.

Pseudoish-code:

```
current_position = buffer;
while (*current_position != '\0')
{
    end_position = current_position + strlen(current_position);
    // The text between current_position and end_position is the sub-string
    // Extract it and add to list
    current_position = end_position + 1;
}
```